# Show that there exists $c\in G$ such that $O(c)$ is least common multiple of $O(a)$ and $O(b)$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be group such that $a,b$ $\in$ and $ab=ba$. Let $O(a)=m$ and $O(b)=n$. Show that there exists $c\in G$ such that $O(c)$ is least common multiple of $O(a)$ and $O(b)$.

i write $d=mk_1$ and also $d=mk_1$ so $c^d=c^{mk_1}=e$. Same thing happens for $d=mk_2$ so i get $c^d=c^{mk_2}=e$. So such c exists. But how do i proceed from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take $c=ab$. Then you have,$(ab)^{l.c.m.(O(a),O(b))}=e$ . Now try to show that $O(c)=l.c.m.(O(a),O(b))$